# What a way to Check range each month For given year for 12 Months?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains the following columns for example:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
| ProcID | Start_Date | End_Date  |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| 001    | 11/1/2015  | 5/31/2016 |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| 001    | 3/12/2017  | 8/23/2017 |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

Query result for the year = 2015 and ProcID = 001

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  Year 2015  |   1  |   2  |   3  |   4  |   5  |   6  |   7  |   8  |   9  |  10  |  11  |  12  |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Static Text | 11-1 | Full | Full | Full | Full | Full | Full | Full | Full | Full | Full | Full |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Query result for the year = 2016 and ProcID = 001

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  Year 2016  |   1  |   2  |   3  |   4  |   5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Static Text | Full | Full | Full | Full | 5-31 | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Finally, for example, Query result for the year = 2017 and ProcID = 001

```
+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  Year 2017  |  1  |  2  |   3  |   4  |   5  |   6  |   7  |   8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |
+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Static Text | --- | --- | 3-12 | Full | Full | Full | Full | 8-23 | --- | --- | --- | --- |
+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Is it possible to Build a Query through SQL in Oracle Database?

Comment: I don't understand the first output, but in any case you might want to use a calendar table containing months.

Comment: What do you do what a period of time is within a month.  The problem is not well specified.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, I've got the start date and end date,
If a full month, within the range. set word 'FULL' and if not, put start date and end date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good candidate for a PIVOT operation. As Gordon said, since there may be more than one period beginning or ending in the same year, you need min() to mask NULL from one period with an actual string from the other. And, this will not work (and nothing can work with the output you described) if you have a period that begins and ends in the same month, or if you have one period end and another begin in the same month.

Note also that your sample output is incorrect; since 5/31/2016 is a date, this means that your notation are the day and then the month, so 11/1 means November 1, not January 11.

```
with
     input_data ( procid, start_date, end_date ) as (
       select 001, date '2015-11-01', date '2016-05-31' from dual union all
       select 001, date '2017-03-12', date '2017-08-23' from dual
     ),
     input_values ( procid, year ) as (
       select 001, 2015 from dual
     ),
     m ( m_idx, m_start, m_end ) as (
       select level,
              add_months( to_date(to_char(year) || '-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), level - 1),
              add_months( to_date(to_char(year) || '-01-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), level - 1)
       from   input_values
       connect by level <= 12
     )
select * 
from   (
         select m.m_idx,
                case when d.start_date < m.m_start and d.end_date > m.m_end 
                                           then 'Full'
                     when d.start_date between m.m_start and m.m_end 
                                           then to_char(d.start_date, 'mm-dd')
                     when d.end_date   between m.m_start and m.m_end 
                                           then to_char(d.end_date,   'mm-dd')
                end  as descr
         from   input_data d cross join m
         where  d.procid = (select procid from input_values)
       )
pivot ( min(descr) for m_idx in (1 as "1", 2 as "2", 3 as "3", 4 as "4", 5 as "5",
        6 as "6", 7 as "7", 8 as "8", 9 as "9", 10 as "10", 11 as "11", 12 as "12") )
;
```

**Output**: (edited to fit)

```
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12 
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
                                                            11-01 Full
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really tricky form of conditional aggregation.  Here is an idea:

```
select substr(min(case when s_yyyymmdd <= yyyy || '0101' and e_yyyymmdd >= yyyy || '0201' then '1FULL'
                       when s_yyyymmdd <= yyyy || '0101' and e_yyyymmdd >= yyyy || '0101' the '2' || substr(e_yyyymmdd, 5)
                       when s_yyyymmdd <  yyyy || '0201' then '3' || substr(s_yyyymmdd, 5)
                       else '4---'
                  end), 2) as "1",
from (select t.*, to_char(start_date, 'YYYYMMDD') as s_yyyymmdd,
             to_char(end_date, 'YYYYMMDD') as e_yyyymmdd,
             '2015' as yyyy
      from t
     ) t
where procId = '001';
```

The subquery converts the dates into strings.  This makes it easier to manipulate with the years.  Because you could have a range such as 2015-01-01 - 2018-12-31, handling the years is tricky.

The logic is then:

- If the period starts before the month and ends after then month, then 'FULL'
- If the period starts before the month but ends in the month, then the end date without the year.
- If the period starts during the month, then the start date without the year.
- Otherwise `---`.

However, we need to aggregate this over all periods, because there might be multiple periods in one year.  The `min()` and first character handle this.  Not pretty, but it just might work.